# Qual a lógica por trás do "dias * 24* 60* 60* 1000"?

Tags: matemática, cookies

Lendo algumas coisas sobre *cookies*, sempre observo o cálculo `dias * 24* 60* 60* 1000`

Qual o raciocínio lógico por trás disso?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

É só uma matemática básica, quantas horas tem um dia? Quantos minutos tem uma hora? Quantos segundos tem um minuto? Quanto milésimos tem um segundo? É só isso, achar o número de milésimos de segundo de um dia sem precisar decorar um número como <strike>84.600.000</strike> (viu? errei, o certo é 86.400.000). Em geral a precisão numérica de tempo é medida em milésimos de segundo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado Maniero!

Comment: Ou de não precisar de abrir a calculadora fazer o calculo e copiar para o código hehe.

Answer (score 4):

Vou usar um exemplo pratico do site [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)

Temos a seguinte função, na qual recebemos o nome, valor e o tempo em dias para que o cookie expire.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Pegamos a data atual

```
var d = new Date();
```

Então a data atual é somada a quantidade de dias em milissegundos, já que precisamos em milissegundos é realizado o calculo dias*24*60*60*1000

```
 d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
```

Formatamos o tempo para expirar

```
var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
```

> String resultante "expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"

Então setamos o cookie

```
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
```

> É setada a seguinte string "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;"

*Então este calculo é feito para transforma a quantidade de dias em milessegundos já que a função "setTime" soma valores em milessegundos.*

[Fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)